# SerializerMethodField always returns the same value and excludes fields

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an API that sends some sample data. I am trying to change the representation of the output, using Django's SerializerMethodField(). But it doesn't work as expected since I am always getting back the same data and the fields are not shown in my output.

I have three models that look like this: 2 Models which are related through foreign keys:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.machine_name
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

And one model like this:

```
class Simulation(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    machine                 = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    project                 = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

I create data like this:

```
test_api_local(method="post", data={"machine":2, "project":1 })
```

What I'd like to achieve is that when I send data with machine:2, it should write the name of this machine2 into the result. 
Like `'machine' : 'machinenametwo'`.

I tried this using SerializerMethodField. I know it is ReadOnly, but since I do not actually change the data only manipulate it I thought something like this might work:

```
class SimulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    machine = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    project = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = Simulation

        fields = ('project',
                  'machine',     
                  )

    def get_machine(self, obj):
        print(obj.machine)
        project_name = obj.project.project_name
        return str(project_name)
```

This does not work, since my field machine doesn't appear anymore. Also when debuggin it (with that print statement), I realize that no matter what data I send, it always prints out the name of my first machine.

If I do `test_api_local(method="post", data={"machine":2, "project":1 })` it prints the name of machine 1.

If I do `test_api_local(method="post", data={"machine":3, "project":1 })` it prints the name of machine 1. So same result....

So my question would be: Is what I try the correct way of doing it, and if so what am I doing wrong.

If it is not, what would be the way?

Thanks so much in advance for any help or hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a 1 for machine is because that is the default for the field.  You're getting the default value because `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is a read only serializer, so it won't accept the input.  If you use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` then it will accept your data.

```
class SimulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    machine = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Machine.objects.all())
    project = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Project.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Simulation
        fields = ('project', 'machine')
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend for taking your time to answer! I will accept this answer even though I went a different way. I ended up doing the logic in my view, overwriting the post method. In your opinion, is it better to do it in the view or to use the PrimaryKeyRelatedField? Because if that is the better way I'd change my code using this.

Comment: I think it's better to put this in the serializer for sure.  There are some use-cases for manipulating the data in the view, but for this case where the serializers can easily handle the incoming data it's more appropriate to leave this to the serializer.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Late follow-up question. I tried to change my code accordingly, but if I use your recommendation I get a ```AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.``` Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Ah, so I suppose I missed something, I've added the `queryset` argument to my answer.  Usually you just want to provide the entire model queryset `queryset=Machine.objects.all()` for the field to validate your input against.  In more complicated situations you might create a custom serializer field class that uses the `context` of the serializer, i.e. to filter the queryset by a kwarg in the view.

Comment: Ok that got rid of the error, thank you. But it is still not updating my fields. In fact the print statements don't print anything anymore. So I assume my get_machine method is useless or being ignored now. Would I have to write a different method?

Comment: Ok I managed. I had to delete the methods I wrote and set the name fields of my models (machine, project) as primary keys